# Does android have a time cycle for checking push notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm investigating why sometimes my application has a delay to receive push notifications and cause of that, I had been doing some tests with my app(built with xamarin) in three different devices with android 7, 9 and 10, using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com) to send notifications.

I noticed these behaviors:

- If device screen is on, android receives the push notification instantaneously;
- If device screen was turned off recently(you were using the phone few minutes ago), android receives the push notification instantaneously also;
- If device is inactive for a considerable time, android can has a delay of minutes(until 15 ~ 20 minutes) to show the push notification;

My conclusion was android seems to have cycles of time to check for notifications. When you turn off screen, the device seems to enter on "stand by" mode after some minutes. If you send notification in the middle of this time you get the notification instantaneously since android is active yet. But if you send the notification when the device is on this "stand by" mode it shows the notification only at the next cycle, what can cause that delay.

It it alright to affirm that?

In addition I wanted also say that configuring the notification importance/priority as High on firebase side and application side, didn't change this behavior. Can this be something related to FCM service or is this the real android behavior?

My apologies for the long question, this is consuming me for some days.

Comment: Have you read up on [Android's Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang no... I will start doing that. Thank you.

Comment: checkout "High Priority" notifcations - "High priority. FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing " - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm already using priority as high, maybe what occurred is that I didn't click at all notifications, was descarting them since are for testing purposes and doing this can cause loosing priority, as fcm docs says.

Comment: "High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized" - you're supposed to click high priority notifications, discarding them is exactly what might lead to deprioritization (notification is spam/unwanted, so there's no reason to deliver them quickly).

Comment: @Pawel it was exactly what I did (lol). But what about Aliexpress app notifications? they send a lot of spam and I always get them instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see at [Android's Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), the behavior described at my question is exactly what android does! But we can solve that by using high priority notifications, in my case, I fixed it by adding these parameters to FCM SDK:

```
'android'=>['priority'=>'high'],
'apns'=>['headers'=>['apns-priority'=>'10']],
'webpush'=>['headers'=>['Urgency'=>'high']]
```

You can read more about that at [FCM Cloud Message docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)